Nginx Setup for WordPress: Facing 301 Redirect Issues
We are planning to move away from Apache/Httpd to Nginx for our wordpress site. I thought the challenge for me would only be while adding the .htaccess codes in nginx configuration but now I am getting 301 redirect from the site whenever I enable nginx.
I am trying to keep the setup simple for now just to see my homepage coming live. Please find the configuration file below.
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /var/www/html/;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

I have setup SSL redirection from AWS ALB at the moment.
It is able to access my healthcheck file but not main wordpress site
Issue: The main WordPress site is not accessible, but it works fine when using Apache/Httpd. There are no apparent issues in the error logs.
What am I missing in the configuration? Any help is appreciated!

make sure you check (and update) the database options for siteurl and the other one like i posted in my 'solution'... clear wp cache. Also, add a index directive for nginx to use index.php as default file. VERIFY wp-config doesnt have hardcoded site options in there like url and such... whatever is in your .htaccess file should be reflected in nginx config if anything in there is customized... if all atill fails, have php be verbose about errors either on screen or have a debug log started... this is an easy fix when you have access to files and DB...

Thanks to the answer above that I got start and which also started me to show the light at the end of the tunnel since I was able to my site up and running.
But it was not a solution for me since I had to make Nginx work with ALB SSL/443 listener.
The solution was pretty much easier and got it on Reddit at the end.
Solution:
Add the following line in wp-config.php above require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');:
 /* Turn HTTPS 'on' if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO matches 'https' */
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

The full explanation of the issue can be found here

First off, that .htaccess file should be ported completely if it contains anything useful/customized when moving from Apache to Nginx.
You have not set any rules for processing PHP files and not set any file as the index file for Nginx config.
index    maintenance.php index.php index.html index.htm;
The 301 redirect comes from conflicting WP config and database entry for 'siteurl' and 'home' being hardcoded to a conflicting value from any previous declaration elsewhere.
Make sure you are updating all links within the database with the current and correct domain name/url as if you were migrating the site from one place to another.
The update_option lines work WONDERS for quickly updating such values in WP database. Remove after they have been used as to not slow down website and oberload it with TONS of SQL operations.
Nginx php location block should also be used properly with at least (not exhaustive list here)
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
Within the same block containing the proxy_pass directive. Something similar to this would be a good base, assuming you can substitute values for yours.

Wow, thanks for pointing on SSL thingy, I removed HTTPS listener from ALB and then updated my wordpress siteurl and home to http, now it works fine. Thanks again, I think now I can start from here. :)
